# How to add crontab in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, cron

I am trying to add a job to my crontab in FreeBSD but it is not working :

I have used this to add the job:  `sudo crontab -e -u vaibhav`

```
@daily /home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy
```

but it is not working. Is there any way to check whether crontab is able to run this script, like `--run-parts` in `Ubuntu`?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Does the editor refuse to save the file, or does the script not get invoked as you expect?

Comment: The script does not get invoked .....

Comment: What does `/home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy
` do? Could you show us the source?

Comment: Does `/home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy` has executable permissions? Is there anything getting mailed from cron (errors)? Is there anything the log file? (`/var/log/cron` under FreeBSD). Is cron itself running (does `pgrep cron` return anything)?

Comment: scrapy : `#!/bin/sh

cd /home/vaibhav/scrapyprog/comparison/eScraperInterface/ && scrapy runAllSpiders`

Comment: pgrep cron returns this :
`32093
31254
940  And yes scrapy has executable permission 
`

Comment: And log has this entry only : `(vaibhav) CMD (/home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy)
Aug  9 03:39:21 ns4007186 crontab[14643]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (vaibhav)
Aug  9 03:40:00 ns4007186 crontab[14643]: (root) END EDIT (vaibhav)
`

Comment: If you change `@daily` to `* * * * *` and wait 2 minutes, does it run? Is your local mail configured correctly (run `echo hello | mail -s test vaibhav` and check that you do receive the mail)?

Comment: when i looked at the mail sent by the crontab i found out that i have given wrong path in the `scrapy` script ...Thanks man for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting up a cron you have to keep in mind a lot of thins

1.The user for which you are trying to set the cron must have permissions over the script i.e. executable permission

`chmod +x /path/to/scrapy`

2.The other imporatnt thing is to make sure that manually the script performs the action it is intended to.

3.Make sure that the enviroment variables are like the way your script requires like set the environment variable by appending the following lines

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`
`export PATH`

4.If still the cron doesn't execute check the cron logs, what kind of errors does it shows.

5.Try logging the output of your script to a log using the following lines in cron

`@daily /bin/sh /home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy > /mylog.log`

6.As far as I can see it must be a shell script so you must define it like this in cron job by giving the complete path for the sh binary and scrpay must be in .sh file.

`@daily /bin/sh /home/vaibhav/applications/comparison/scrapy.sh`

[More about cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: when i looked at the mail sent by the crontab i found out that i have given wrong path in the `scrapy` script ...Thanks man for help

Comment: Glad to help... :)